# Django Paginator. How to set number of pages or elements of list

Tags: django

I need to create a `Paginator` object for `function based` `view`. When I send a request to googleapi I receive `json` with `totalItems` and `items` keys. GoogleApi paginates request to 10 items. Let's say the `totalItems` is 800 so I need to somehow tell Django `Paginator` there are more items than I receive in the request.

My first idea was to just create a list with empty items and items received from API at indexes accordingly to page number but I believe there is some good clean trick for that"

**VIEW**

```
def get_books(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    start_index = (page - 1) * 10 
    params = {'q': RoweryMogąUratowaćŚwiat, startIndex: start_index}
    result = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?,params=params)
    total = result['totalItems']        
    items = result['items']
    my_list = []        
    for i in range(total)
        if start_index < i < start_index + 10
             my_list.append(items[i - start_index])
        else:
             my_list.append('')

    paginator = Paginator(my_list, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def get_books(request):

    result = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?,params=params)
    items = result['items']
    
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(items, 10)
    
    try:
       data = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
       data = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
       data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)    

    return render(request, 'books.html', { 'data': data })
```